# using winhttp to connect to a multihomed host when the first ip is bad

Tags: c++, winhttp, multihomed

im trying to confirm that the feature described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384066(VS.85).aspx

> WINHTTP_OPTION_CONNECT_RETRIES Sets or
>   retrieves an unsigned long integer
>   value that contains the number of
>   times WinHTTP attempts to connect to a
>   host. Microsoft Windows HTTP Services
>   (WinHTTP) only attempts once per
>   Internet Protocol (IP) address. For
>   example, if you attempt to connect to
>   a multihomed host that has 10 IP
>   addresses and
>   WINHTTP_OPTION_CONNECT_RETRIES is set
>   to 7, then WinHTTP only attempts to
>   connect to the first seven IP address.
>   Given the same set of 10 IP addresses,
>   if WINHTTP_OPTION_CONNECT_RETRIES is
>   set to 20, WinHTTP attempts each of
>   the 10 only once. If a connection
>   attempt still fails after the
>   specified number of attempts, or if
>   the connect timeout expired before
>   then, the request is canceled. The
>   default value for
>   WINHTTP_OPTION_CONNECT_RETRIES is five
>   attempts.

actually works.

my code is:

```
int main()
{   
  DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
  LPSTR pszOutBuffer;
  BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
  HINTERNET  hSession = NULL, 
             hConnect = NULL,
             hRequest = NULL;

  // Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
  hSession = WinHttpOpen( L"WinHTTP Example/1.0",  
                          WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
                          WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, 
                          WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0 );
    DWORD data;
    DWORD dwSize = sizeof(DWORD);
    if (hSession)
    {


        // Use WinHttpQueryOption to retrieve internet options.
        if (WinHttpQueryOption( hSession, 
                                WINHTTP_OPTION_CONNECT_RETRIES, 
                                &data, &dwSize))
        {
            printf("Connection Retries: %u \n\n",data);
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "Error %u in WinHttpQueryOption.\n", GetLastError());
        }        
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error %u in WinHttpOpen.\n", GetLastError());
    }

dwSize = 0;

   // Specify an HTTP server.
  if( hSession )
    hConnect = WinHttpConnect( hSession, L"google.com",
                               INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0 );

  // Create an HTTP request handle.
  if( hConnect )
    hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect, L"GET", NULL,
                                   NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, 
                                   NULL, 
                                   NULL );

  // Send a request.
  if( hRequest )
    bResults = WinHttpSendRequest( hRequest,
                                   WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0,
                                   WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 
                                   0, 0 );


  // End the request.
  if( bResults )
    bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse( hRequest, NULL );

  // Keep checking for data until there is nothing left.
  if( bResults )
  {
    do 
    {
      // Check for available data.
      dwSize = 0;
      if( !WinHttpQueryDataAvailable( hRequest, &dwSize ) )
        printf( "Error %u in WinHttpQueryDataAvailable.\n",
                GetLastError( ) );

      // Allocate space for the buffer.
      pszOutBuffer = new char[dwSize+1];
      if( !pszOutBuffer )
      {
        printf( "Out of memory\n" );
        dwSize=0;
      }
      else
      {
        // Read the data.
        ZeroMemory( pszOutBuffer, dwSize+1 );

        if( !WinHttpReadData( hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer, 
                              dwSize, &dwDownloaded ) )
          printf( "Error %u in WinHttpReadData.\n", GetLastError( ) );
        else
          printf( "%s", pszOutBuffer );

        // Free the memory allocated to the buffer.
        delete [] pszOutBuffer;
      }
    } while( dwSize > 0 );
  }


  // Report any errors.
  if( !bResults )
    printf( "Error %d has occurred.\n", GetLastError( ) );

  // Close any open handles.
  if( hRequest ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hRequest );
  if( hConnect ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hConnect );
  if( hSession ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hSession );

    getchar();

 return 0;
}
```

one way to test this is to place this in your C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file:

```
123.123.123.123 google.com

66.102.7.99 google.com
```

type

```
ping google.com
```

(this should fail)
then

```
ipconfig /displaydns
```

and you should see two dns records for google.com.

as stated above, the default value is 5 which means it should go on to try the second ip, but it isn't.  what am i missing?